# iphone a2dp codecs supported

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

I am looking around to see what audio codecs are supported by the a2dp profile on the iphone (3.0 i guess).

aac, apt-x, mp3, etc...

anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the iPhone only implements SBC, though the information available directly from Apple isn't exactly forthcoming about that. (I suppose since that's only going to matter to accessory hardware vendors, and not to platform developers.)

See, as examples, [this forum discussion](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2087488), and [this blog post](http://www.wirelessaudioblog.com/archives/532) (rant).

Answer (score 1):

This may have changed since the question was first asked but the iPhone supports AAC LC according to this 2013 document:
https://developer.apple.com/hardwaredrivers/BluetoothDesignGuidelines.pdf